# Git repo on an SD card sometimes renames origin/master to origin/MASTER

Tags: git

I sometimes work between computers, so putting projects in a git repo is really useful. The issue is I don't always work somewhere with a connection to git, so I create repos on my SD card. It works pretty much the same as having a repo online, except for this one issue where `origin/master` every once in a while gets renamed to `origin/MASTER`. It's happened twice now, and I have no idea what triggers it. I see it when I go to push to the repo and it fails because it still tries to push to `origin/master`, and since it doesn't exist anymore, it tries to create it, but it can't because there is already a `origin/MASTER` and the SD card's filesystem is case-insensitive. At least that's what I think is happening.

Comment: I don't know what might cause it, but you should be able to fix it by renaming the appropriate file under `.git`. Run `find .git -iname master` to see what files are affected. You'll probably need to do the rename in two steps: `mv MASTER master_ ; mv master_ master`

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, I'll do that next time, the way I fixed it this time was just delete branch `origin/MASTER` and push again.
I still need to figure out why it happens tho

Comment: It's fat32 formatted, yes? Is it possible that the parent repo contains something (a branch, a tag, whatever) called `MASTER`? (I'm grasping at straws.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I made the original repo with `git init --bare` and for my first push from local clone I did `git push -u origin master`, the issue is I never created anything called `MASTER`

Comment: That's weird. There are no occurrences of `MASTER` in the git sources (except as a variable name in a couple of test scripts). Another possible workaround might be `git branch -m MASTER master`. If it happens again, do a `find .git -iname master`. There should be 4 such files: `.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master`, `.git/logs/refs/heads/master`, `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, `.git/refs/heads/master`. Seeing which of those changed might provide a clue. What OS are you using to access the SD card?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'll check which next time it renames, thanks.
I go between windows and linux. It might be something from switching between them that's causing the issue but I don't thinks so, I'm pretty sure there were several times I switched from one to the other and it didn't rename. Btw, I think it happens when I'm on my windows machine, I know that's where I had the issue the 2nd time, I can't remember if the first time was on my windows machine or my linux one.